# TS-Express : What does “./bin/www” do in Express 4.x? How to convert it into TS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('event-internal-app-be:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {

        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string' ?
        'Pipe ' + port :
        'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ?
        'pipe ' + addr :
        'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

This is my ./bin/www file.

And this is my app.ts file

```
import express,{ Application } from "express";

let app: Application;

app = express();
app.listen(1010,()=>{
    console.log("hi")
});
```

This is not working properly when converted to TypeScript. I have mentioned tsconfig file properly.

Error thrown :
/home/x/y-project/z-Backend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:139173
var error = new Error("Could not find source file: '" + fileName + "'.");
^
Error: Could not find source file: '/home/x/y/z-Backend/bin/www'.

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/www` is the "main program" or startup program that `express-generator` creates when you generate the framework for a new express app. The generator also places its name into `package.json`.

With all respect to the creators of `express-generator`, it isn't a whole lot of use for a long-lived production app. Your best bet is to just rewrite it.